# Multiples with x/y axis and mouseover example - line path shows wrong values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to combine severeal D3.js examples based on [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1157787). I managed to get mouseover for each multiples chart in part working (values are not displayed at mouse pointer yet but via console.log). By checking those values I realized that my line paths at the upper two charts are off in relation to the Y-Axis, also causing the mouseover focus to be in the wrong place. I am new to D3, so I am still having trouble to pin down the problem beeing caused by domain/scale/axis etc. You can see the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u6OsFvnDDt4jwljyVyr5?p=preview)

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  //shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.area {
  //fill: #e7e7e7;
  fill: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 30},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 138 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse,
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,
    formatValue = d3.format(",.2f"),
    formatCurrency = function(d) { return formatValue(d); };

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)         // x is the d3.time.scale()
  .orient("bottom") // the ticks go below the graph
  .ticks(4);        // specify the number of ticks

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(4);

d3.csv("stocks_chart2.csv", type, function(error, data) {

    // Nest data by symbol.
    var symbols = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.symbol; })
      .entries(data);

    // Compute the maximum price per symbol, needed for the y-domain.
    symbols.forEach(function(s) {
    s.maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.price; });
    });

    // Compute the minimum and maximum date across symbols.
    // We assume values are sorted by date.
    x.domain([
    d3.min(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(symbols, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
    ]);

    // Add an SVG element for each symbol, with the desired dimensions and margin.
    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
      .data(symbols)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the area path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return area(d.values); });

    // Add the line path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]); return line(d.values); });

    // Add a small label for the symbol name.
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 6)
      .attr("y", height - 6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

    svg.append('g')            // create a <g> element
      .attr('class', 'x axis') // specify classes
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") 
      .call(xAxis);            // let the axis do its thing

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

    var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

    focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
        var date, index;
        date = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        index = 0;
        var focus = svg.selectAll(".focus");
        focus.attr("transform", function(d) {
            index = bisectDate(d.values, date, 0, d.values.length - 1);
            console.log(index, d.values[index].symbol, d.values[index].date, d.values[index].price); 
            return "translate(" + x(d.values[index].date) + "," + y(d.values[index].price) + ")"
        });

        focus.selectAll("text", function(d) {
          return formatCurrency(d.values[index].price);
        });
    }
});

function type(d) {
  d.price = +d.price;
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  return d;
}

</script>
```

How do I assign the correct Y-Axis to each individual multiples chart causing the line path and mouseover values to be at the correct position? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  The example you link to uses a single `y` scale and `yAxis` for all 4 sub-plots.  In your situation, though, your data has a very different *domain* for each sub-plot and when you add the dynamic mouse over a shared scale just won't work.  So, my solution would be to create a different `y` scale and `yAxis` for each subplot.

```
...

// variable to hold our scales
var ys = {};

var area = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) {
    return ys[d.symbol](d.price); //<-- call the y function matched to our symbol
  });

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return ys[d.symbol](d.price); //<-- call the y scale function matched to our symbol
  });

...

// for each symbol create our scale
symbols.forEach(function(s) {
  var maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function(d) {
    return d.price;
  });
  ys[s.key] = d3.scale.linear() //<-- create a scale for each "symbol" (ie Sensor 1, etc...)
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, maxPrice]);
});

...

// build 4 y axis
var axisGs = svg.append("g"); //<-- create a collection of axisGs

axisGs
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Value");

axisGs.each(function(d, i) { //<-- for each axisG create an axis with it's scale
  var self = d3.select(this);
  self.call(
    d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(ys[d.key])
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(4)
  );
});

...

// adjust mouseover to use appropriate scale
focus.attr("transform", function(d) {
  index = bisectDate(d.values, date, 0, d.values.length - 1);
  console.log(index, d.values[index].symbol, d.values[index].date, d.values[index].price);
  return "translate(" + x(d.values[index].date) + "," + ys[d.key](d.values[index].price) + ")"; //<-- finally in our mouse move use the appropriate scale
});
```

Fully working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCAXo4Y55mHZsot5VjKH?p=preview).

Comment: Hitting the nail on the head! Thanks a lot! Still trying to get my head around scale/axis etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as best practices are concerned when you are dealing with n number of datasets you have to go for n number of y scales and their corresponding y axis. It is good for seperation of concern and keeps the visulization intact. here you can see the example.

http://grafitome.github.io/advanced-charts.html#(first chart)

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to get the concept! Thanks for the cool examples!